# How to limit file upload size to prevent XSS attacks using up server space

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, socket.io, xss

I have developed a node application that allows users to upload profile and other images. I have validation on both client and server to check the file type and size. However I recently became aware of the fact that a malicious attack could involve bypassing the form validation on the client side and uploading huge images just to use up server disk space.

How is this preventable in node/express? I should point out that I am also using socketio so would like to know how to limit the data size sent via socketio too.

In principle the logic (in my head) would be straightforward...I know that a file upload should never exceed 1MB in my application. As soon as the data received exceeds that I want to just cancel the request and send a 400 response or something. And perhaps ban the ip.

I did read about a solution involving clearing the temp folder periodically but wouldn't it be better to stop the request mid process as soon as the file exceeds a file size limit?

What is a simple and effective solution to this? Is it a common attack and is it something worth worrying about for a small website?

What about limiting socketio data to say under 10 KB and disconnecting the socket if the data transfered exceeds that? Is this necessary or possible?

Comment: It depends on what you're using to handle file uploads. Are you actually transferring files through socket.io?

Comment: Express handles the general image file uploads for users profiles.

I am not transfering files over socketio but a hacker could presumably quite easily by pass the client side socket, hijack on of my emit events and send a whole books worth of text over the socket every second or something which would mess with server performance.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I just think about how could you prevent user upload files continuously, that might cause storage filled up, the only solution I could think is to add a limit usage for every single account, but user could still create a new account, thus, It's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use request filter and check the content-length in it. If content-length is more than allowed value you can simply return from there only.